# Desabilitar infobar do Chrome ao executar teste automatizado

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit

Tentei implementar um método que fará com que a janela do Chrome seja maximizada e a infobar ao iniciar os testes seja desativada, porém ao executar não acontece nenhuma das duas ações. As ações estão no método `desabilitaInfoBar`, alguém saberia me auxiliar no caso?

```
package tests;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestName;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import com.sun.media.jfxmedia.logging.Logger;
import okio.Options;

public class TesteEstruturado {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    // Inicializando o Google Chrome
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    @Rule
    // Instanciação dos testes (@Before, @Test e @After)
    public TestName teste = new TestName();

    // @Before cria um hook que será executado antes de cada teste.
    // Sendo um estado que o sistema deve estar antes de executar o teste

    // Metodo que maximiza a janela do Browser antes que os testes sejam
    // iniciados

    /*@Before
    public void maximizaTelaBrowser() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    */

    @Before
    public void desabilitaInfoBar() {
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    }

    // Abertura da página em que será iniciado o teste
    @Before
    public void abreBrowser() {
        driver.get("https://automacaocombatista.herokuapp.com/users/new");
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    // @Test define cada caso de teste que está sendo automatizado
    @Test
    public void confirmaCadastro() {
        // Após acesso a página de cadastro e se iniciando um novo será feito
        // preenchimento dos dados solicitados
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_name")).sendKeys("Bruno");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_lastname")).sendKeys("Nogueira Andrade");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_email")).sendKeys("bruno.nog.andrade@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_address")).sendKeys("Rua professor nelson de senna, 115, ap 31");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_university")).sendKeys("Sistemas de informação/Estácio de sá");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_profile")).sendKeys("Analista de teste/QA");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_gender")).sendKeys("Masculino");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_age")).sendKeys("27");

        // Clicando no botão Criar
        driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();

        // Verificando se os dados cadastrados na tela anterior são os mesmos
        // registrados na tela de confirmação
        if ((driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText().contains("Nome: Bruno")
                && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText()
                        .contains("Ultimo Nome: Nogueira Andrade")
                && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText()
                        .contains("Email: bruno.nog.andrade@gmail.com")
                && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText()
                        .contains("Univercidade: Sistemas de informação/Estácio de sá")
                && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText()
                        .contains("Gênero: Masculino")
                && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText()
                        .contains("Profissão: Analista de teste/QA")
                && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText().contains("Idade: 27")
                && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col s12 center']"))).getText()
                        .contains("Address: Rua professor nelson de senna, 115, ap 31")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados inseridos estão correpondentes aos cadastrados");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados inseridos não estão correspondentes aos cadastrados");

        }
    }

    @After
    public void fechaBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para maximizar a tela  e remover a infobar você deve depois adicionar o driver recebendo o ChromeDriver

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    //adicione isso apos os argumentos
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```